# Nifi Tailfile processor always ingesting full files

Tags: apache-nifi, tail

My Tailfile processor keeps taking the entirety of the file I'm tailing.  This creates a situation where I have a 20mb file that is added to my flow, then about a minute later, I'll have a 21mb file, etc.  Why is it doing that?  Here are the configurations

[image]

Know that I have this processor feeding my nifi flow through minifi.  So it is local on the machine, then sending it through a remote process to my nifi

Thanks!

Edit: File listing
[image]

Comment: Can you please specify versions, host environments, and perhaps provide a sample file listing of your source files tailed?  At first glance, the rolling filename pattern in conjunction with single file mode seems like it could be an issue.

Comment: I'm on version 1.1.2 and this is running on Windows Server.  I will add a picutre of the listing

Comment: What version of minifi are you using?  1.1.2 is a NiFi release.  My understanding is that you have minifi tailing the file and forwarding to NiFi.  Please let me know if my understanding is incorrect.  Thanks!

Comment: @apiri you are right.  The Minifi version is 0.2.0

Comment: We have found that the content repository was filling up once the error started.  Could this be an issue? @apiri

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have sufficient privileges on file and directory to read.
And you should set Initial Start Position to Beginning of Time